# Why can good music raise goosebumps?

Tags: music, hearing

Listening to really good music right now, I was wondering why it raises goosebumps.

Is there any physiological reason for this reaction to specific wavelengths or something?

Due sometimes strong vibration, roadwork for example, raise goosebumps too I reckon it's about the wavelengths but if someone could explain what is happening and why, that would be great.

[CROSS-POSTED](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29661/why-can-good-music-raise-goosebumps?noredirect=1#comment48350_29661)

Comment: This is called [frisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisson)